# Hide parts of page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

I am creating a communication site in SharePoint which has members in it. The problem is that I don't want the members to know who else is in the group since this is a communication site for external vendors. How do I hide the members in the group which appears in the top right corner?

See the picture below.

[image: Members which to hide]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the members on the top right corner, you may need scripts such as CSS.

In SharePoint Online modern experience, we need to use [SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to add scripts to "modern" pages.

Check [Information about Customizing the "modern" experiences in SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Another workaround, you could switch the experience from modern to classic. The members are not appeared in classic experience.